# (Django) filtering objects in view

Tags: django, django-views

I have 2 classes in model

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

and I want to filter objects of B which does not have 'a' not has name of "exclude".

I tried

```
objects = B.objects.exclude(a.name == "exclude")
```

in my view, but it does not work.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
objects = B.objects.exclude(a__name="exclude")
```

or

```
from django.db.models import Q
objects = B.objects.filter(~Q(a__name="exclude"))
```

but the former one is good enough..

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
objects = B.objects.exclude(a__name="exclude")
```

Comment: No need to use all() `objects = B.objects.exclude(a__name="exclude")` should work

Comment: Only with default manager class. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters

Comment: Which is the case here, in the 90% of cases :), but I get your point.

Comment: Though arguably, if the manager class overrides `exclude`, that should be the default method you use, not `all().exclude()`.

Comment: Yes, you have right. `all()` isn't necessary. I've edited my answer.